# Можно ли отобразить создать круговой график на языке Javascript, используя Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Вопрос заключается в следующем. Есть задача с собеса на верстальщика. Сверстать страницу по макету, используя для создания графиков Chart.js. Не могу понять как сделать круговой график, представляющий из себя три кольца вложенных друг в друга. Буду очень признателен за любую подсказку

Пробовал использовать диаграммы, Polar area charts и Pie and doughnut charts, но не сообразил как придти к нужному результату

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так-то там примеры есть и документация.

Comment: нужно, что ба на каждом из трех колец были отображены точки. кроме этих точек на кольцах больше ничего быть не должно